# Understanding the grammar of もしてたり

Tags: grammar

> ゆめみ「わたしがこうして引きこもりから脱出できたのは、逢桜さんが親切にしてくれたのも理由のひとつだから……」
>
> ゆめみ「優しくて、真っすぐて、カッコよくて……そんな逢桜さんに憧れてました」
>
> ゆめみ「わたしも逢桜さんみたいな女の子になりたいなって、思ったり**もしてたり**……あはは」
>
> ゆめみ「本当に……ありがとうございました」

逢桜 was going to study abroad and her classmates and schoolmates held a farewell party for her. At the party, ゆめみ, her 後輩, said the above sentences.

I understand the meaning of the second last sentence but not the grammar of もしてたり. Could you please the grammar of the bold part? I only know the ……たり……たりする construction.

Answer (score 2):

This たり is a kind of softener explained in the following questions. In this context, it's working as something like "maybe", "kinda" or "happens to ...".

- [Meaning of ーたりしない](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55396/5010)
- [What does 良いところだったりする mean in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/52637/5010)
- [How do I translate 「コロッと転がってたりする」 to english?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30808/5010)
- [What is the meaning of 〜たりして?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5705/5010)
- [Meaning of noun + だったりする](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13714/5010)

～と思ったりしてて and ～と思ってたり are already reserved sentences, but she wanted to make it sound as mild as possible, so she used たり twice. This も is [another softener](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/51841/5010).

> って、思ったりもしてたり……
> I happen to be thinking, like, maybe, ...