# Can verbs ending with たり act as a noun?

Tags: grammar

While reading a certain manga, I found this sentence

> 小さい頃オレは何をするにも人の目が気になって自分の意見を言うのが苦手でさそれで後悔することも多かったけど嫌われたりが怖かったりでできなくて

I am curious about the 嫌われたりが怖かったり part. It is understood as "scared about getting disliked." I wonder how it is different from 嫌われるのが怖い. When verbs end with たり can function like nouns? Are there any other examples?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, たり can work like a long noun. See:

- [Is する omitted from ~たり~たりする because the main predicate is an adjective?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/91416/5010)

There is little difference from 嫌われるのが怖い, but here たり is used to add a certain exclamatory nuance. See:

- [Meaning of ーたりしない](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55396/5010)
- [What does 良いところだったりする mean in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/52637/5010)
- [How do I translate 「コロッと転がってたりする」 to english?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30808/5010)